# Is there a find () of a map to use a comparator with parameters?

Tags: c++, dictionary, find

To explain, what I want, let there is a map

```
std::map<Point, SomeClass> hm_map;
```

Is there a way to use in a `find ()` of a map the comparator with parameter? - the radius of interesting me Point, so the `find ()` must return the set of proper pairs. I think, I have chosen the incorrect container for it.

---

Edit:

```
comparator::distance = someNumber;
setOfProperPairs = hmap.find (key, comparator);
```

where

```
struct comparator
{
 static double distance;
 bool operator()(Point ptg, Point p) const
 { return ptg.Hit (p, distance); }
};
```

Do you know what the container to use for it?

Comment: std::map has a find() by searching over key of map<key,value>. What is the key you are going to pass to  find function?

Comment: Yes, you have chosen the incorrect container. A map's internal data structure is determined by the ordering, the comparison function must be consistent or it can't work.

Comment: @Steephen comparator::distance = someNumber;
hmap.find (key, comparator);
where
struct comparator
{ static double distance;
   bool operator()(Point ptg, Point p) const
   { return ptg.Hit (p, distance); }
 };

Comment: @Mark Ransom, do you know what the container to use for it?

Comment: There's nothing ready-made in `std`. The search terms are "spatial search", "space partitioning trees" etc. I understand your query as "all points within a certain distance of each other." If you know a reasonably accurate maximum of the distance you'll be searching in advance, a grid or quadtree/octree might be applicable.

Comment: @so-litary if that is the case find(key) should return the iterator  to the pair and you can use (iterator->first,iterator->.second)  to retrieve the data. I am not sure is that you are looking for.

Comment: That static double distance; in the comparator is no good

Comment: It's not _incredibly_ complicated to write something that could return a set of iterators to the `Point`s in question though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::map` supports one-dimensional sorted data.

If you want geometric sorting in two or more dimensions, there is no `std` support for that.

You will want a quad tree (or oct tree or higher dimensional analogues), or an r tree, or a kd-tree, or similar.

They are a bit tricky to code.

Now, if you know the radius you care about before you build your structure, you can hack a simpler implementation.  Create a square n dimensional grid where the spacing between the grid sides is about 1/2 to 2/3 said radius.

Store data in a multimap from grid cell to exact location and data.

Now when doing a lookup, figure out what grid the center is in, work out what grid cells could have hits in them, and search through said grid cells, doing a final check on the location to see if it is a hit.